# Calculating correlation of different time series

Tags: python, matlab, time-series, correlation

I have several time series, i.e. I have measured a couple of signals over 15min. Each signal is sampled several times each second but the timestamps of the different signals are not equal. Let's say we start at time 0s. For example, signal one has the following (timestamp, values):

```
0.1s: 954
0.2s: 1000
0.24s: 1090
0.3s: 855
0.45s: 600
...
```

Signal two has the following (timestamp, values):

```
0.05s: 900
0.13s: 960
0.2s: 1000
0.29s: 850 
0.33s 800
...
```

How can I now calculate the correlation of the values of these time series in e.g. python or Matlab? If the values would be always at the same timestamps I could calculate just the correlation between the individual values but unfortunately the values are not at the same timestamps.

Comment: Interpolate to the same timestamps, then calculate the correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a signal with values in an array `s1` at time points `t1`, and a signal `s2` evaluate at time points `t2`. With [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) in Python:

1. Select a common set of time points for both signals `t`. You can pick `t1` or `t2`, or compute a linear space in the considered time range with [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). In any case, I'd make sure that the minimum and maximum values of `t` are in the range of both `t1` and `t2` to avoid extrapolations.
2. Compute interpolations for both signals, `s1interp` and `s2interp`. This can be done with [`np.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), which computes linear interpolations. If you need more sophisticated interpolation methods, you can take a look at SciPy's [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).
3. Compute the correlation between `s1interp` and `s2interp`. This is done with [`np.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jdehesa.

With the corrcoef I'm getting a matrix of valus. How can I aggregate it to a single value estimating the correlation?

Comment: @machinery Right, I forgot, `np.corrcoef` gives you the Pearson correlation _matrix_. Since it's just two variables here, you can take either the element `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]` (it's the same value), which should be in the range `[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say both signals correlate but they are shifted in y-direction (one signal has lower amplitude). How can I compensate for this if I don't know the value of the shift? I don't want to incorporate this shift into the correlation value.

Comment: @machinery Mmm, I'm not sure I follow... are you actually looking for the [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) ([`np.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)) or for a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) ([`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html))?

Answer (score 2):

You could do some simple interpolation (see [`interp1`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for MATLAB) on one of the data sets so that they share a sampling rate, if that's your only issue...

```matlab
X =[0.1   954
    0.2   1000
    0.24  1090
    0.3   855
    0.45  600];

Y =[0.05  900
    0.13  960
    0.2   1000
    0.29  850 
    0.33  800];

t = Y(:,1); % get time samples from Y
% Interpolate (linearly, with extrapolation) X2 values onto time samples t
X2 = [t, interp1(X(:,1), X(:,2), t, 'linear', 'extrap')];

>> X2 = [0.05  931
         0.13  967.8
         0.2   1000
         0.29  894.1667
         0.33  804];
```

Now they have the same sample points, you can do what you like.